# Unexpected behaviour in indexing data.frame by row name

Tags: r, subset

I don't use indexing data.frame by row name very often but there is an advantage to do it sometimes. However I've noticed unexpected result when I've tried to filter unexciting row

```
  test <- data.frame(a = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                     b = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                     row.names = c(-99.5, 99.5, 99))
  test["-99", ]
```

You would expect it will give you

```
     a    b
NA <NA> <NA>
```

but it returns

```
      a b
-99.5 a A
```

Just to be specific

```
Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.441)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
 tz       Europe/London
```

Any ideas?

Comment: probably some fuzzy matching mechanism already used when calling a function.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no function here. This bug on empty environment.

Comment: This is a great example of why you should always use logical conditions for subsetting/indexing. TRUE or FALSE is ridiculously more reliable and intuitive than named references. Also, tends to be easier to debug.

Comment: I totally agree and I do, but for this case I need to keep the order of test data.frame. When you index by logical condition the ordering will depend on indexing vector, not origin table. Anyway, will find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed unexpected.

The answer to this lies in the partial matching of row names when indexing:

```
mtcars["Val", ]
```

Will give us the "Valient" row. This wont work for columns:

```
mtcars[ ,"cy"]
```

To eliminate this, I'd subset using:

```
subset(test, rownames(test) == "-99")
```

Edit: It is indeed documented in `?"[.data.frame"`

> Both [ and [[ extraction methods partially match row names. By default
>   neither partially match column names, but [[ will if exact = FALSE
>   (and with a warning if exact = NA). If you want to exact matching on
>   row names use match, as in the examples.

To use match on your data:

```
test[match("-99", row.names(test)), ]
```

Comment: I now realise that I did read the question wrong. Good answer (+1).